# get distinct rows from list of 'games'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show a list of games by date organized so that I have one entry for each game. The table consists of two entries for each game, the example data illustrates the layout. I can get the Home vs Away filtered easily by just filtering on the 'A' in Location. My problem is only getting one of the teams when the location is 'N' for neutral site. The creation SQL and version info is below.

The desired result of the query would be:

```
('2011-08-01', 'Mustangs', 'Indians', 'A'),
('2011-08-14', 'Bulldogs', 'Indians', 'N'),
('2011-08-22', 'Braves', 'Bulldogs', 'A')
```

I'd tried doing a sub-select to get only Team2 where it wasn't already in Team1 list when location=N but I couldn't get it to work successfully. For the purposes of this query, there are no other available fields to make the 'game' unique and the structure of the table can not be changed.

Any help is appreciated.

```
-- Server version: 5.1.56
-- PHP Version: 5.2.17
-- Table structure for table `testTbl`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testTbl` (
  `gameDate` date NOT NULL,
  `Team1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Team2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  KEY `gameDate` (`gameDate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
-- Dumping data for table `testTbl`
INSERT INTO `testTbl` (`gameDate`, `Team1`, `Team2`, `Location`) VALUES
('2011-08-22', 'Bulldogs', 'Braves', 'H'),
('2011-08-22', 'Braves', 'Bulldogs', 'A'),
('2011-08-01', 'Indians', 'Mustangs', 'H'),
('2011-08-01', 'Mustangs', 'Indians', 'A'),
('2011-08-14', 'Bulldogs', 'Indians', 'N'),
('2011-08-14', 'Indians', 'Bulldogs', 'N');
```

Comment: What would happen if Bulldogs play against Braves two times on one day? What would you like to see as result?

Comment: Doesn't `SELECT DISTINCT` work?

Comment: Why can't you change the structure of the table? I think a better solution to this problem would be to come up with a different way to represent the location, so that you don't need duplicate records.  For instance, instead of a `Location` column you could have a `Home_Team` column which could be either team's name, or `NULL` in the case of a neutral match.

Comment: @Konerak it's not possible in this system, the combination of team1, team2, and date is unique.

Comment: @Mitch I will eventually, but this is an inherited monster that needs a complete redesign and this query will meet a short term need.

Comment: @Bobby - Ah, I see.  I've been there before ;)  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM testTbl t
WHERE location = 'A' OR 
 (LOCATION = 'N' AND team1 <= team2)
```

This will, for each record pair, only show the records where Team1 is (alphabetically) smaller than team 2.

So Bulldogs-Indians will be shown, but Indians-Bulldogs won't.